Fix failed to get sink information warning
After upgrading Ubuntu LTS from jammy to 24.04 noble, logging in hangs with a movable white pointer over black background for a long time, then a graphical message appears that the system "failed to get sink information" in my profile, possibly related to some audio driver, but no helpful details other that I "should fix it".

Warning
Error found when loading /home/ingo/.profile:
Failed to get sink information: No such entity
As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.
OK

Does anyone know this message and how to fix?

My .profile file contained a command to raise the speaker volume above "100%" because some tutorials I needed to watch had shallow sound. I guess this setting is no longer supported in Ubuntu 24.04, or it requires additional software that got deactivated during the update.
Removing the line in ~home/.profile fixed the issue:
# allow louder sound
pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 150%


So the problem was not while the system was starting up, but actually while you are logging in. 24.04 changed the sound system from pulseaudio to pipewire.

Thanks, I added my question accordingly and added the pipewire tag. You could post an answer, not a comment by the way.

Posting an additional answer seems pointless since you already figured out the problem.
